# Protractor stale element reference when using the each() method

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am getting the error below as a result of using the each() method in protractor. It has worked fine in the past but is now consistently failing with this error.

> Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

`element.all(bars).each((element) => element.getCssValue('width'))`

Is there an alternative or a reason why this might be?

(For clarity, all I want to do is to get the width of each element in a set of web elements called bars.)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you executing this after the page has been completely loaded?

Comment: Yes, I check that a loading wrapper has disappeared before executing. ```browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(element(loadingWrapper)), 6000);```

Comment: But that code does not stop javascript execution. You should probably use the promise returned by `browser.wait` and only when it resolves do the `element.all(bars).each` loop.

Comment: Hi @trincot thanks, for your help. It ended up being a timing issue. I added a .then(() => browser.driver.sleep(1000)) and it now works perfectly. It confused me initially because it had worked perfectly in the past. I think this must be down to network delays or priorities in protractor. Thanks again :)

Comment: This sounds like a hacky solution. It would be better to wait for `browser.wait` to resolve.

Comment: Okay I'll try that, thanks :)

Comment: I don't think this is the fix but I have a sort of nit with this question. You are redefining your global `element` object locally here. Could you please reword this to not redefine `element`?

Comment: Another question, is there anything else that is happening in this test? Your lines above or below this one line could cause the staleness. This will improve the type of answers you will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped. The solution was retry again if it resulted in error. Due to the realtime nature of the element, the element reference was changing before it had got the css width.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, it happens because `each()` just fires commands simultaneously against all elements. In your case you probably need to go this way `element.all(bars).getCssValue('width')).then(array => {/*do what you want with returned array here*/})`

*** Edited ***

What you want to do is

```
element.all(bars).getCssValue('width')).then(array => {
    // tests is at least one element will not be "0px"
    let elementHasWidth = array.some(elem => elem !== "0px");
    expect(elementHasWidth).toBe(true);
})
```

Comment: Thanks @SergeyPleshakov I tried this method but didn't have any luck. My original code ```element.all(bars).each((element) => element.getCssValue('width').then((value) => (value != '0px') ? isNotZero = true : null))``` where isNotZero is a boolean variable set to false. It checks if at least one bar has a width greater than 0px. When I try as an array I get the same problem as before.

Comment: Is the problem perhaps that they are all trying to access isNotZero simultaneously?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you're trying to get `width` of all specified elements and if any of them is greater than 0 return `true`?

Comment: @Isabella updated^ if works please mark the answer as correct, else lmk we'll make it work anyway!

Comment: Thanks @SergeyPleshakov unfortunately that didn't work either. Here's what I tried, it's slightly different from yours but I assume it should work similar to what you intended. ```element.all(bars).each((element) => element.getCssValue('width')).then((array) => 
        {
          let elementHasWidth = array.each((elem) => (elem !== "0px")? true: false);
          expect(elementHasWidth).toBe(true);
        })```

Comment: I am getting a very similar problem where suddenly my calls to .filter and .forEach are failing with stale element reference errors.  After burning nearly a whole day on it, I'm tempted to simply re-write my tests to locate each element individually one at a time.

Comment: @emery can you describe your what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3):

New problems like this with existing code are likely due to Protractor and Selenium evolving from Web Driver Control Flow and WebDriverJS Promise Manager to native promises. You used to be able to write code that looked like synchronous code and under the hood the toolkits would convert it to asynchronous code that waited for the DOM to load and JavaScript on the page to run. Going forward you [need to convert your code](https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await) to explicitly use `async/await` or promises. (See the reasoning behind the Selenium change [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969).)

Unfortunately a lot of old (pre 2019) examples, even in the Protractor documentation, are written in synchronous style, so you should be careful about following them. Even more unfortunately, [you cannot mix `async` code with Control Flow code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3037), and if you try, all the Control Flow will be disabled, and probably some of your tests that relied on it will start failing.

By the way, what is the value of `bars`? A Protractor `by` object works differently than a native WebDriver locator and I'm not sure they are reusable. Try using `by.name('bars')` or whatever instead of `bars`.

Your case is tricky because of all the promises involved. `element.getCssValue` returns a promise. Since you are trying to get a `true` or `false` value out of this, I suggest using a reducer.

```
let nonZero = element.all(by.name('bars')).reduce((acc, elem) => {
  return acc || elem.getCssValue('width').then( (width) => width > 0 );
}, false);
```

In a more complicated situation, you could use `all().each()` but you have to be careful to ensure that nothing you do inside `each` affects the DOM, because once it does, it potentially invalidates the rest of the array.

If you are potentially modifying the page with your ultimate action, then, as ugly as it may seem, you need to loop over finding the elements:

```
for (var i = 0; true; i++) {
  let list = element.all(by.css('.items li'));
  if (i >= await list.count();)
    break;
  list.get(i).click();
};
```

Comment: @emery Let me know if this does or does not address your issue.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I did not write or edit the original question, I just put the bounty on.  You mention async/await: Do you have any specific reason to believe that using it will clear up stale element reference errors from inside .each(), .forEach(), .filter() blocks etc?  If so, then it sounds like that's likely to be the most graceful fix.

Comment: @emery Yes, I listed the specific reasons I think async/await will help in the first 2 paragraphs of my answer. I cannot be more specific to your situation without seeing your full code in context.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code before your error statement:

```
  browser.wait(function() {
        return element.all(bars).isPresent().then(function(result) {
            return result;
        });
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: This won't work, because specified function will wait for the first element to be present and not for all. @isabella if in your case it is not relevant, but once I got away from the same issue by browser.sleep() when I was using each() but for different purpose. Just FYI for the future