# How to execute one element then and then another in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, async-await, protractor, automated-tests

This following code behaving randomly sometime it works fine and sometime it throws error like this `Stale Element Reference Exception`

what i want is i want to get this below executed first

```
element(by.id('FiltItemTransDocNo')).sendKeys(grno);
```

after above i want this to get executed this below

```
element.all(by.name('chkGrd')).first().click();
```

i have tried this way but it didnt seems to work

```
element(by.id('FiltItemTransDocNo')).sendKeys(grno).then(function(el){
     element.all(by.name('chkGrd')).first().click();
});
```

help me out with this

i have attached the image
i am sending keys to Purchase Rquisition field and according i came up with result which will show only one result and i want to click 
and if i will put condition for visiblity it will always be `true` then i will lead to same issue
[image]

Comment: I think your `.click()` is a promise that needs to be awaited for (like this: `await element.all(by.name('chkGrd')).first().click();`)

Comment: it will need async @HaunsTM

Comment: @JeffC yes i do, it is because the dom element not present

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A quick note on `sendKeys` and `e1`

A quick note that [`sendKeys`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L1997) does not return a WebElement or ElementFinder. This means that e1 in the example above is probably undefined.

### Stale elements and the DOM changing

**Quick note on assumptions:** The answer has an assumption that sending text to a filter would change the row count or number of elements on the screen. If there are the same number of elements on the screen after you send in the text, then this would not work. I would look at Florent's comment below on the stale reference error.

Stale elements usually happen when the DOM has changed. If you are using some structural directive in Angular, the DOM will change if you are using *ngFor or *ngIf. My guess is that after you filter the the element, you are getting the elements in the DOM during or before the DOM actually changes based on your filter. This would result in a stale referenced web element. In my examplex below, I am using async / await with the control flow off.

#### Explicit wait during the filter

You could explicitly set a sleep so the DOM will update before you make a call to click the first element. This could lead to potentially flaky tests because the timeout is unknown based on the environment you will run in.

```
it('should do something', async () => {
  const filterItem = element(by.id('FiltItemTransDocNo'));
  await filterItem.sendKeys(grno);
  await browser.sleep(1000);  // or some other waits
  await element.all(by.name('chkGrd')).first().click();
});
```

#### Compare rows for element.all

Alternatively you could do a comparison check for the amount of `element.all` items you have before and after the click and only move on when things are updated.

```
it('should do something', async () => {
  const filterItem = element(by.id('FiltItemTransDocNo'));
  const table = element.all(by.name('chkGrd'));
  const length = await table.count();

  await filterItem.sendKeys(grno);

  // After the filter keys are sent, check to see if the current table
  // count is not equal to the `table.count()`.
  let updated = false;
  await browser.wait(async () => {
    updated = length !== await table.count();
    return updated;
  }, 5000);

  // So if we use the entire 5 seconds and the count has not changed,
  // we should probably fail before clicking on stuff.
  expect(updated).toBeTruthy();

  // now we can click on the next element.
  await element.all(by.name('chkGrd')).first().click();
});
```

Why does calling `length !== await table.count()` work? This is because the table represents a promise to get the web element. When you call the `count` method, it executes the action by first resolving the web element. This could potentially be different depending if the DOM changes. We then compare the current count to the previous one.

#### Making sure you are using async / await

In your configuration file, you will need to specify that you are off the control flow:

```
exports.config = {
    // In this case, I plan to use a selenium standalone server
    // at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub. You could also use other 
    // methods like direct connect or starting it up with 'local'.
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',

    // Required flag to tell Protractor you do not want to use the
    // control flow. This means that you will have to either chain
    // your promises or async / await your actions. Historically
    // jasminewd node module would resolve promises for you. This
    // package will no longer be used in future releases since the
    // control flow is deprecated.
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

    // The rest of your config...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: okay 1 quick question is there not any way where i can bind two DOM element and chain them in such way that the execute 1 after another

Comment: Most things are fine except with Angular structural directives which ends up changing the DOM (that's my assumption for the answer above). After a user types, there is probably some timeout that happens to signal that the user is done typing. The app will then filter out based on the input. You are not guaranteed that you have the right element.all unless you check.

Comment: Also, yes you'll need to use async / await. If you are not, you should think about it... since the next version will not work without async / awaiting promises.

Comment: this seems working with 1 browser instance will try with multiple instance too Thanks for your help

Comment: A static delay should never be used to wait when the refresh time is non-deterministic. And by waiting for the count of elements to be updated, you could fall in the case where the content is updated with the same number of elements, which is common with pagination. A better approach would be to wait for a previous WebElement/reference to become stale.

Comment: I think this is something the user would have to decide when writing the test. I made an assumption that filtering would have less elements on the screen. If the user has the same number of elements on the screen after the filter text is sent and the DOM does change, then your stale reference error does makes sense.I will edit my answer slightly with assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

there is several solutions for stale element reference.

First:

```
    let filterItem = element(by.id('FiltItemTransDocNo'));
    browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(filterItem), 5000, 'Element is not visible.');
    filterItem.sendKeys('some random text');

    let elementToClick = element.all(by.name('chkGrd')).first();
    browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToClick), 5000, 'Element is not clickable.');
    elementToClick.click();
```

You can also chain them:

```
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(filterItem), 5000, 'Element is not visible.').then( () => {
                filterItem.sendKeys('some random text');

                browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementToClick), 5000, 'Element is not clickable.').then( () => {
                    elementToClick.click();
                });
            });
```

Or second way, to refresh the element on stale error:

```
let filterItem = element(by.id('FiltItemTransDocNo'));

            try {
                filterItem.sendKeys('some random text');
            } catch (e) {
                if (e instanceof StaleElementReferenceError) {
                    filterItem = element(by.id('FiltItemTransDocNo'));
                    filterItem.sendKeys('text');
                }
            }
```

Comment: yup because visiblity will return true in my case the element is always there  so it will not wait

Comment: what i want is chain them in such way that sendkeys perform first then and then click get executed

Comment: When you wish to click on element, condition visability of can be true, but the element to not be clickable, thats why there is such condition 'elementToBeClickable();'

Comment: it sends key but does not clicks the ele

Comment: and if i put `browser.driver.sleep(500);` this then it works but it not seems feasible to me

Answer (score 2):

As I explained in an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53842797/712765), Protractor and the tools it uses are all changing to use native JavaScript promises, with the expectation that everyone will migrate their code to a fully async style of coding. Unfortunately, they are not making it easy because you cannot mix the old style code with the new style. So first things first, make sure you entire suite is written async style and you have set `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in your config.

What happens in response to the `sendKeys`? If that triggers an AJAX call and the response to that call changes the DOM, then you are probably going to have to do what @cnishina suggests and poll the DOM to wait for the change to land. If, however, only Angular client-side changes happen, then this code should work:

```
it('should do something', async () => {
  await element(by.id('FiltItemTransDocNo')).sendKeys(grno);
  await element.all(by.name('chkGrd')).first().click();
});
```

Both `element` calls synchronize with Angular to make sure that Angular updates are finished before the locators proceed, so you should be OK as far as Angular is concerned.