# getText function throws stale element inside array.map()

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to use array.map function to find the text properties of all the webelements stored in an array.  Is there any way to handle this and retry finding the text property?

standard solution with normal for loop for retry is an option. Wanted to check for alternate solutions.

```
 let name_planogram_table = await element.all(by.xpath(planograms_Table_cart_Category));

 let uistringvaluearray = await Promise.all(name_planogram_table .map(name=> name.getText()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Protractor's `each` should do the trick.

```
let uistringvaluearray = await name_planogram_table.each(async arrayElement => {
   return arrayElement.getText()
   //This is just a quick example
   //return the value, assign to another variable or do whatever you need to do
})
```

Comment: wouldn't this throw stale element reference ? @Yuriy Gerasimovich

Comment: Even thou `each` is asynchronous it should not cause any issues. As Sergey Pleshakov mentioned there was a bug some time ago but personally for me it works with a list of 10+ elements at this moment (in my case I have a list of similar elements and my test needs to verify is there an element with desired text)

Comment: It will throw the same error, unless this was fixed in protractor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365309/protractor-stale-element-reference-when-using-the-each-method/53381322#53381322

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get these values simply by calling getText() on your elementFinderArray like so

```
let name_planogram_table = await element.all(by.xpath(planograms_Table_cart_Category)).getText();
console.log(name_planogram_table);
```

It will produce a array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

1. `await` keyword resolves a promise. `element.all(by.xpath(planograms_Table_cart_Category))` is NOT a promise, hense no need to `await` it
2. As mentioned above, this will work

```
let name_planogram_table = await element.all(by.xpath(planograms_Table_cart_Category)).getText();
console.log(name_planogram_table);

// output
// [
//   "value1",
//   "value2",
//   "value3"
// ]
```

BUT!!! There was a bug a year ago (maybe it still persist), when you call `.getText()` or `.getAttribute()` against A LOT of elements (30, 50, 100+) you get `stale element` error. The only solution in this case was `for` loop